# Javascript regex: make different spaces depending on lenght: 1 000, 10 000, 100 000

Tags: javascript

So, I have this string, which can contain a number of any length really.

```
10
100
1000
10000
100000
```

I need a regex which makes the strings like this:

```
10
100
1 000
10 000
100 000
```

For 100000, I have made this: `/.{1,3}/g`, but that only works from 100 000 and up.
Is this possible?

Comment: @kjelelokk Can you please search on google before asking questions here? Please

Comment: @NULL I did, guess I have poor Google skills. Also didn't know they were called thousand separators, English isn't my first language. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically you want thousand separators.

Look into [`number_format` on PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/), or use this simplified version:

```
var num = 10000;
alert((""+num).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g," ")) // 10 000
```

Comment: If `num` have more than 3 decimals the result will look something like this: `var num=1234.5678` => `1 234.5 678`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [the code on phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/).

He's created a Javascript function to mimic php's `number_format()`.

This is copy/paste and I stripped comments:

```
function number_format (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
  number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
    prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
      var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
      return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
    };
  // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
  }
  if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || '';
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
  }
  return s.join(dec);
}
```

I take no credit for this code.

Comment: Kolink uses Quick Attack :p

Comment: Really shouldn't +1 that but had to. :P Made me giggle and it's been a long day trying to learn Ada.